# Testing mongodb queries in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to test my mongoDB queries in node.js.
I'm using the native mongodb [driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb).
Up until recently I was using [tingodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tingodb). But this module is not supporting node mongodb 2.x.

So as far as I'm concernded I have two options
 1. Not to update my mongoDB node module to 2.x (currently using 1.4). This is obviously a bad idea.
 2. In my tests, I can either connect to a local mongoDB instance and test my code using it. The downside is that the tests might run slower.
 3. Write some node code that will start/stop a mongo process on the local machine

What would be the best approach?
Am I missing another npm mondule that can solve my problem?

Comment: you can use mongoose

Answer (score -2):

Why not [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)?

#### Installation:

```
  npm install mongoose --save
```

#### Usage:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('meow');
  }
});
```

A good tutorial is [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications)

Comment: What you are suggesting is exactly as what I proposed, connect to a local instance. It doesnt matter if I use mongoose or native driver. I'm familiar with mongoose but it will require a major changes in the project which I currently can't find a good enough reason to switch.